# javascript variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope

I'm writing a small Flickr image grabber app, and we have a JSON proxy on our own servers. The function below grabs the images from a photoset given the `id`.

```
function getPhotosFromPhotoset(p_id) {
    var data;
    $.getJSON('/flickr_get_photos', {
        photoset_id: p_id
    }, function(res) {
        data = res;
        console.log("res: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        if (res.status == 'ok') {
            if (res.data.length > 0) {
                //nada                                                                                                                            
            } else {
                data.status = "error: Photoset has no photos.";
            }
        } else {
            data.status = "An unknown error occurred; please try again.";
        }
    });
    return data; //undefined?!
}
```

Why is does `data` suddenly become undefined? When I `console.log` it inside of the `getJSON`, it's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function returns long before the ajax request is even made. Use `data` in the callback function (You are actually logging it in the callback function, where it's guaranteed to be available ). The `$.getJSON` doesn't take callback function just for fun, but exactly for this reason.

You can do this though:

```
function getPhotosFromPhotoset(p_id) {
    return $.getJSON('/flickr_get_photos', {
        photoset_id: p_id
    });
}

getPhotosFromPhotoset(1).then(function(data) {
    //Use data here
});
```

Instead of trying to do:

```
var data = getPhotosFromPhotoset(1); //will not work
```

Which will not work unless you set the request to synchronous, which has worse problems.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't suddenly become undefined. `getJson` is an asynchronous call, the function that sets the `data` value is what gets call when the server returns a response, `getPhotosFromPhotoset` doesn't wait for the server to respond before completing execution and thus the data value has not been set with anything yet.

Comment: How can I make it wait for the call to finish?

Comment: You don't want to, synchronous server side calls block page functions. You need to refactor the function that calls the getPhotosFromPhotoset function to expect a call back and not a return value.

Comment: I'm confused as to how I'd use a callback... what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

AJAX executes asynchronously, so when you say:

```
return data; //undefined?!
```

That code is executing *before* the code in `function (res)`, which is why `data` is undefined. If you want to do something with the `data`, you need to pass a callback function to `getPhotosFromPhotoset` which will be executed by the `success` callback of `getJSON`.

Does that make sense?